# Error can't find variable media when record voice in ionic2 (ios)

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic-view

I tried record voice in ionic2 view in ios. But get this message:

> Can't find variable media.

When running in emulate works fine.

This is my code:

```
var pathAudio: string = 'mmmm.wav';
this.fileRecord = new MediaPlugin(pathAudio);
```

Whats my error?? Is necessary some other configuration?